# PHP JAVASCRIPT HOW TO HIDE <div> or disable radio when user select today's date

Tags: javascript, php

I'm kinda new in PHP and Javascript.

How can I hide or disable that radio or hide the `<div>`
that radio is inside of `<div>`.

For example: the user select today's date but the time is already 4 pm how can hide or disable the radio or `<div>`.

CODE FOR SELECTING CODE

```
DATE FOR APPOINTMENT: 
 <input name="dateapp" type="date" class="datepicker" id="dateapp" required>
```

CODE CHOOSING TIME

```
<H6> MORNING </H6>
<input name="timeapp" type="radio" class="boxcheck1 filled-in" id="test1" value="9:00 AM TO 12:00 AM"/>
<label for="test1" class="cyan-text"> 9:00 AM TO 12:00 AM  </label>

<H6> AFTERNOON </H6>
<input name="timeapp" type="radio" class="boxcheck2 filled-in" id="test2" value="1:00 PM TO 4:00 PM"/>
<label for="test2" class="cyan-text"> 1:00 PM TO 4:00 PM  </label>


<H6> NIGHT </H6>
<input name="timeapp" type="radio" class="boxcheck3 filled-in" id="test3" value="4:00 PM TO 7:00 PM"/>
<label for="test3" class="cyan-text"> 4:00 PM TO 7:00 PM  </label>
```

[image: FORM]

Comment: Would help if you posted your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like following

```
<input type="radio" id="x">
  <input type="datetime-local" onchange="radioDisable(this.value)">
```

And a script which has a function named `radioDisable` that can disable your radio button, which will be as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       var button = document.getElementById("x");
       var d = new Date();
       function radioDisable (val)
       {
               if (val == d.toDateString())
               {
                     button.disable = true;
                }
       }

</script>
```

The above code will disable radio button with id x, if the date chosen is the current date.

Note: the line `d.toDateString()` will automatically check if the the selected date is the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
var curTime = new Date();
var day = curTime.getDay();
curTime = parseInt(curTime.getHours() + "" + ("0" +  curTime.getMinutes()).substr(-2) + "" + ("0" +  curTime.getSeconds()).substr(-2));

if (curTime < 173000)
  console.log("It's a good time!");
else
  console.log("It's not a good time!");
```